# Convert INT column to Datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column as `int` and it stores year like `2017`.

How can I convert this to  save the result to another actual datetime column like `2017-01-01`?

Comment: which version of sql-server?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATEFROMPARTS is a new SQL Server function, (from SQL Server 2012), that allows to build a date value using its parts: Year, Month, Day.

Have a look at [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) at MS Docs.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET    <UpdColName> = DATEFROMPARTS(<IntColName>,1,1)
WHERE  <some condition>
```

Comment: Thankls alot for your assist

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Comment: Although this does answer a question, it does not (in my opinion) answer the question being asked:  "Convert Int Column to Datetime in SQL".

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql).

```
select datefromparts(colname,1,1)
from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks, But how can I update or save the result to another column ?

Comment: how would like to update? and which column?please post all the details in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DATEFROMPARTS`,

```
UPDATE table SET coldatetime= datefromparts(colname,1,1) WHERE colname = 2017
```

Comment: Thanks  for your assist

Answer (score 1):

This is complicated.  First, convert the column to a `varchar()`:

```
alter table t alter column col varchar(255);
```

When you do this, the integer will be converted to a `varchar()`.

Next, append '0101' to the value:

```
update t
    set col = col + '0101';
```

This puts the value in the form `'YYYYMMDD'`, which SQL Server recognizes as a date.

Finally, alter to a date:

```
alter table t alter column col date;
```

If you like, you can add another column to the table for the date and do this in two steps:

```
alter table t add column datecol date;

update t
    set datecol = concat(intcol, '0101');
```

Although you can also use `datefromparts()`, the above should work in earlier versions of SQL Server as well.

Comment: Thanks and see McNets answer.

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif . . . Your question implies that you want the column itself altered, not that you want the value in another column.